# Why was the world of Sword Art Online not just dominated by good real-life fighters?

Tags: novel, sword-art-online

There are many people in real life who practice fencing for fun. Most of them (at least most of those around me) also play computer games about fighting. Sword Art Online clearly fits into the fighting genre of computer games. I didn't make a survey, but in any game about fencing it is certainly possible to find someone who likes do the same things in real life.

As I recall, in the world of SAO combos are quick, but very predictable, especially the strong ones, and their speed is not above human limits.

As I assume, if one real-life swordsman would get his hands (or his mind) on SAO, he would wreck everyone. One can move his weapon without combos, losing some speed, but getting a *huge* advantage of being able to use feints. Plus he would be able to stop his attacks to block enemy's blow, etc.

Yes, he would probably be weaker at the beginning due to not knowing the animations yet and most of combos being very short. But at higher levels he could both identify a combo by first "frames", plus quickly react. It would also be nearly impossible to hit him unless he doesn't expect an attack.

Why did this not happen in the novel, why was it dominated by a bunch of Mary Sue-esque characters? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Reading US Army field manuals and practicing in real life has made me better at FPS games, but none of that is going to help me beat a 5yo who plays CoD 8 hours a day. Mastering a video game's mechanics has little to do with the real world.

Comment: You may also want to ask on [anime.se], they specialize in anime such as this (though it's certainly on-topic here, being scifi/fantasy).

Comment: @Mazura Did you read SAO? :)

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Will do it if I don't get answers here.

Answer (score 3):

Fencing like any other martial arts, relies on repetition that will ingrain certain movements into your body's muscle memory.  The aim of this is to be able to do a set pattern of movement/movements without your brain getting in the way.

SAO's Nerve Gear translated your thoughts into action in that world.  So Kirito the titular hero, who had the fastest speed of thought/reaction time was awarded the "dual wield" skill by the Cardinal system.  The take away from this is speed of thought.

Real life fencer's who had trained their bodies to peak condition would lose a lot of their trained body's advantage in SAO.  They would have the advantage of experience to know which movements were more efficient to do in battle, but they would need to translate and retrain their skill into thought action versus pure muscle memory all over again to be effective.

Comment: Muscle memory is still largely a mental process, not just some change to the muscles themselves. It is essentially remembering and refining the series neurological commands sent to the muscles. I am not familiar with the source material, but I guess this would boil down to what is considered thought there.

Comment: What Jack said, plus knowing the movements (like from historical manuals) would still be a great advantage, so would be feints, so would still be attacking the enemy while he tries to make a combo even if muscle memory is lost (at least you know *what* to retrain). Also dual blades are very far from the best weapon combination, even if they look cool -- shield gives much more opportunity to block, second blade, for various reasons, doesn't improve your hit spead that much, and a two-handed sword or a polearm would get the advantage of length. An experienced reenactor or fencer would know this.

Comment: What about Kirito makes him the 'titular' hero?